# Is this ok to average p values?

Tags: r, p-value, combining-p-values

I have seen other posts about averaging p values. I believe I have a special case where average may apply.

Finding the exact probability distribution of my data is an NP hard task, so I am using a non deterministic algorithm to estimate my p value. The algorithm was published and validated on experimental data. Because it is non deterministic, I have repeated the same test 1000 times.  In this case I think it would make sense to report the mean p value along with the standard deviation.  In most cases standard deviation is < 0.05.

For combining p values, I would use Fisher's method, but the 1000 tests are not independent.  They are just non deterministic iterations of the same test.  This is why I want to use mean p.  Reporting mean and standard deviation would be a more descriptive estimate of the p value rather than running the algorithm just one time.

Searching through the literature, I found a few things that appear to contradict the idea that a p value cannot be averaged:

Using harmonic mean p value for dependent tests
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6347718/

different ways of combining p values via averaging
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6347718/

Comment: In such a situation, averaging p values would make sense to me, but I'm no expert. What kind of algorithm are you running? I could see this as feasible if you were doing, say, a bootstrap or a permutation test using random permutations. Probably better than running the algorithm just once and relying on this one single result...

Comment: thank you for the feedback @StephanKolassa, that is reassuring. 

I left out describing my test because its a bit of a niche field and I wanted to avoid confusion.  I am using an R package called atSNP to test the effect of a single nucleotide change on the binding affinity of a transcription factor. It estimates the joint distribution of two first order markovian processes via importance sampling. More about that here: 
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26092860/
See the supplementary data pdf section 2.2 "Computing and testing binding affinity score change between alleles"

Comment: Nice, thank you for the clarification. Let me venture an answer. (Incidentally, I also contributed to one or two SNP analysis papers in my wild youth.)

Answer (score 3):

It is quite common to assess statistical significance via resampling, bootstrap or permutation tests, all of which are randomized (see, e.g., [the textbook by Good, 2006](https://books.google.de/books/about/Permutation_Parametric_and_Bootstrap_Tes.html?id=tQtedCBEgeAC&redir_esc=y)). In such cases, people will often run their procedure just a single time and report the resulting p value. More sophisticated modelers will re-run their analysis a few times to see how stable the p values are. (Unscrupulous modelers will re-run them until they get a low p value.)

Running the analysis multiple times and averaging the resulting p values seems to me to be an excellent way of getting more stable p values. Essentially, this treats the p value as an estimate of an underlying test statistic itself (which it is!), and harnesses the power of averaging. The relevant criticisms of p value averaging do not apply. (If anyone disagrees, I would be interested in their argument.)

Comment: Hi @Stephan-kolassa, thanks for the helpful insight!  I very much appreciate you taking the time to write out a clear answer.  I too would be interested in contrary arguments

Comment: In that case, maybe you would like to un-accept my answer. I won't take it personally. Questions with accepted answers typically get fewer views, and fewer additional answers. You can always re-accept my answer later if you feel it is the best one.